# How To change backup path in sql server agent

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-agent

i want to change my backup location of sql server 2008 r2 ,i am using sql server agent to do backup job ,now the drive is full i want to make the backup into other drive.please provide me the steps how to resolve this issue

Comment: Find the SQL Agent Job -> Properties -> Steps -> Find the step that performs the backup and change the path that it writes to

Comment: i have tried these steps but after double clicking on steps option there is no option to change the location.

Comment: What are the steps listed?  Does the job call an SSIS package to perform the backup?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Management>Maintenance Plan> Then select the plan and change the destination auto folder path from the property window

Comment: I don't see the option to change the location of db backup