# Change destination folder in SQL Server Database backup plan

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssms, ssms-2012

I've already created a backup plan in `SQL Server 2012` using their `Maintenance Plan Wizard`. This plans runs every midnight and stores the backups at the default location `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup` . But, after one year, now I want to change it's destination folder where the backups are stored. But I can't find any place where I can make that change. So, I went to its `job menu` where in the `Steps` window I only see the following command. **Question**: Is there any way we can change the destination folder? If not, in the command window shown below, how can I change the syntax so it store the backup to, say, `D:/myNewFolder`

NOTE:

1. This question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23089219/1232087) and [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic781927-146-1.aspx) in slightly different context but with no solutions.
2. Also, the question is `NOT` about changing the default SQL Server backup folder in general (as has been asked [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1583/changing-the-default-sql-server-backup-folder/)). My question is specific to changing the backup folder in my only one backup plan created using Maintenance Plan Wizard)
3. So please answer the question only if you know a solution and/or have tested if before.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `Management -> Maintenance Plans -> Backup Databases` instead of `SQL Server Agent -> Job Activity Monitor`.

[image]

Comment: @Brain I went to `Management -> Maintenance Plans -> Backup Databases` and did not see the screen you're showing. I'm using SQL server 2012. And please note, as I mentioned in my post, this is the plan I created using `Maintenance Plan Wizard`